# Yii, создать приложение из под PHP

Tags: yii

В общем, такая проблема, но нет на данный момент доступа к SSH
Как можно чистым пыхом создать приложение в Yii?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По фтп проще закачать. Можно через композер, но его все равно надо сначала установить/залить, и я не знаю, как к нему напрямую (не из командной строки) обратиться (скорее всего, создать объект команды и вызвать run)

Comment: @Etki получил доступ по SSH, всё равно вкурить не могу, что где и куда.

Comment: @Виталий RS, а что конкретно вам нужно-то?

Comment: @Etki , да вот решил посмотреть, попробовать разобраться. Для начала из демопроектов блог поставить.

Comment: @Виталий RS писалось без тестирования:

    wget https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/releases/download/1.1.15/yii-1.1.15.022a51.zip -O yii-1.1.15.zip
    mkdir /var/www/yii
    unzip yii-1.1.15.zip -d /var/www/yii
    
и натравить севре на нужную папку из demos.